# How to fix <Response [400]> while make a POST in Python?

Tags: python, request, http-status-code-400

I kept getting `<Response [400]>` in my terminal while running the script.

I have tried

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://172.19.242.32:1234/vse/account'

data = '{ 
  "account_id": 1008,
  "email_address": "bhills_4984@mailinator.com",
  "password": "qqq",
  "account_type": "customer",
  "name_prefix": "",
  "first_name": "Beverly",
  "middle_names": "",
  "last_name": "Hills",
  "name_suffix": "",
  "non_person_name": false,
  "DBA": "",
  "display_name": "BeverlyHills",
  "address1": "4984 Beverly Dr",
  "address2": "4984 Beverly Dr",
  "address3": "",
  "city": "Beverly Hills",
  "state": "CA",
  "postal_code": "90210",
  "nation_code": "90210",
  "phone1": "3105554984",
  "phone2": "",
  "phone3": "",
  "time_zone_offset_from_utc": -5,
  "customer_type": "2",
  "longitude": -118.4104684,
  "latitude": 34.1030032,
  "altitude": 0
}'

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

print r
```

---

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: what's the response body?

Comment: How do I see that ?

Comment: [There's a few properties and methods like `.text`, `.content`, `.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

to

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

because data is not a dict that must be transformed to json but is already json.

Comment: wasn't it `json=data`? if you pass `data=data` then it will be encoded as `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: @Kos Ideally, data would be a dictionary and he would pass it using the json parameter instead of data. `requests.post(url, json=data)`