# How to use .p12 certificate to authenticate rest api

Tags: python-3.x, api, post, python-requests, p12

I have received a certificate.p12 with username and password.
While I am able to use Rest Client for post requests after i install this certificate in my system.
How can i use this certificate to authenticate post requests on Rest API using Python requests method ?
I am using below code but it is not working.

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
payload = {'folder': '/Trial/trial_dir'}
response = requests.post('https://<IP>:8080/siteapi/availabletests', params=payload, headers=headers, verify='C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\sigos\\cert.p12', auth=('trial_test','trialtest'))
```

And getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
        conn = self._new_conn()
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
        self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
    urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036B0230>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
        _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IP', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /siteapi/availabletests?folder=%2FTrial%2Ftrial_dir (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036B0230>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
        return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 513, in send
        raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='IP', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /siteapi/availabletests?folder=%2FTrial%2Ftrial_dir (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x036B0230>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

Comment: just to make it clear you are using the requests library right?

Comment: @Fozoro : yes, I am using requests library. Any clue how can i use p12 certificate to post something using requests.post when it is must to use username and password ?

Comment: Can you please post your current code

Comment: @Fozoro : I have just now added my code and trace-back in question.

Comment: try replacing `verify=` with `cert=`

Comment: @Fozoro : I Tried and there seems to be change in exception but post request is still failing.

exception caught HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<IP>', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /siteapi/availabletests?folder=%2FTrial%2Ftrial_test (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03CEB930>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

Comment: hmm well in the case I truly have no idea, really hope someone else will be able to help.

Comment: @Fozoro : What I mean is using "cert" in place of "verify" changed the exception. But no positive results. I am blacked out because  same certificate works with Rest Client and I am able to make the POST requests then why this error in Python requests !!!

Comment: @Fozoro I found the solution. Please check it out in my answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks for tagging me. How did you find it?

Comment: @Fozoro I found this github link and used its code but still i was getting ssl error but difftent than previous one. Then found a question on github n saw that my payload was diffrent than his. I was using dictionary but he used dictionary as string. See this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257168/how-to-fix-response-400-while-make-a-post-in-python

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ref: https://github.com/m-click/requests_pkcs12

I was using payload

```
data={"folder": "/Trial/trial_dir"}
```

which is a dictionary while it should be a proper string of dictionary

```
data='{"folder": "/Trial/trial_dir"}'
```

So the following are the findings for successful post requests with python :-

1. Header parameter should be a dictionary.

e.g.

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

2. Data parameter should be a dictionary in string format.

e.g.

```
data='{"folder": "/Trial/trial_dir"}'
```

3. Verify should be set to False : `verify=False` as to ignore verifying the SSL certificate.

Below is the status and contents received from request I made:

```
>>> import json
>>> from requests_pkcs12 import get,post
>>> url = 'https://IP:8080/siteapi/availabletests'
>>> pkcs12_filename = 'C:\\Users\\ukhare\\Desktop\\tests\\trial_tata.p12'
>>> pkcs12_password = 'trialtest'
>>> response = post(url, data='{"folder": "/Trial/trial_dir"}', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, verify=False, pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename,pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)


D:\m\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
>>> print(response.status_code)
200
>>> print(json.dumps(json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8")), indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), sort_keys=True))
{
    "availableTests": [
        "/Trial/trial_test/HTTP_Download"
    ],
    "serviceError": null
```