# In python, how can we connect to API using a certificate, subscription key?

Tags: python, api, certificate

I am trying to connect to an api for which I was provided with link, certificate(.p12) and subscription key.

Having some issue while giving the certificate details. I am trying in the following 2 ways:
1.

```
    import json
    from requests_pkcs12 import get,post
    url = 'https://....'
    pkcs12_filename = '<certificate file path>'
    pkcs12_password = '<certificate password>'
    headers = {
        # Request headers
        'Subscription-Key': '<subscription key>',}
    response = post(url,  headers=headers, verify=False, pkcs12_filename=pkcs12_filename,pkcs12_password=pkcs12_password)
    print(response.status_code)
```

2. 

```
    import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
    #file = "<certificate path>"
    headers = {
      'Subscription-Key': '<subscriptionkey>',
      #'cert' : crypto.load_pkcs12(open(file, 'rb').read(), "<password>").get_certificate(),
      'file' : '<certificate path>',
      'password':'<certificate password>',}
    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    })
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('<api main link>')
    conn.request("GET", "<api remaining link>" , params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print("Status: {} and reason: {}".format(response.status, response.reason))
    conn.close()
```

I am new to API concept. Will someone help me over this?

Refered to this link: [How to use .p12 certificate to authenticate rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902996/how-to-use-p12-certificate-to-authenticate-rest-api)
But didn't get what i need to put in data variable